# Calculate the average consumption from data in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I need to calculate the average consumption for each engine.

```
    iterables = [['A123B'], ['2021-03-04 10:10:17', '2021-03-04 11:18:51', '2021-03-04 12:50:24', 
                             '2021-03-04 13:02:02', '2021-03-04 14:37:23']]
    control_id = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=["ENGINE_ID", "TIME"])
    steps = [354815, 355160, 355428, 357850, 358314]
    quantity = [156.32, 85.49, 100.00, 157.02, 134.00]
    full = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
    dict = {'CONTROL_ID':control_id, 'STEPS':steps, 'QUANTITY':quantity, 'FULL':full}
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict, index=index)
```

| ENGINE_ID | TIME | CONTROL_ID | STEPS | QUANTITY | FULL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A123B | 2021-03-04 10:10:17 | 1 | 354815 | 156.32 | 1 |
|  | 2021-03-04 11:18:51 | 2 | 355160 | 85.49 | 0 |
|  | 2021-03-04 12:50:24 | 3 | 355428 | 100.00 | 0 |
|  | 2021-03-04 13:02:02 | 4 | 357850 | 157.02 | 1 |
|  | 2021-03-04 14:37:23 | 5 | 358314 | 134.00 | 0 |

The objective is to calculate the difference between the steps that the engine is full, divided by the sum of the quantities.
Like the table above, considering the CONTROL_ID = 5 the difference between the steps would be `(357850 - 354815) = 3035` and the quantities `(85.49 + 100.00 + 157.02) = 342.51`, the average consumption would be `3035/342.51 = 8.86`. In this example, the expected result would be like the table below. I have a dataframe with multiple engines and steps.

| ENGINE_ID | TIME | CONTROL_ID | STEPS | QUANTITY | FULL | AVERAGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A123B | 2021-03-04 10:10:17 | 1 | 354815 | 156.32 | 1 | 0 |
|  | 2021-03-04 11:18:51 | 2 | 355160 | 85.49 | 0 | 0 |
|  | 2021-03-04 12:50:24 | 3 | 355428 | 100.00 | 0 | 0 |
|  | 2021-03-04 13:02:02 | 4 | 357850 | 157.02 | 1 | 8.86 |
|  | 2021-03-04 14:37:23 | 5 | 358314 | 134.00 | 0 | 0 |

How can I calculate and insert the AVERAGE column for the entire dataframe? I looked for similar examples here and in Pandas Documentation, but I didn't find where to start.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

iterables = [['A123B'], ['2021-03-04 10:10:17', '2021-03-04 11:18:51',
                         '2021-03-04 12:50:24', '2021-03-04 13:02:02',
                         '2021-03-04 14:37:23']]
control_id = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=["ENGINE_ID", "TIME"])
steps = [354815, 355160, 355428, 357850, 358314]
quantity = [156.32, 85.49, 100.00, 157.02, 134.00]
full = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
d = {'CONTROL_ID': control_id, 'STEPS': steps, 'QUANTITY': quantity, 'FULL': full}
df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=index)

# Boolean Index for where FULL == 1
full_m = df.FULL.eq(1)
# Get Values Needed For Average For Each Group Between Fulls
sums = df.assign(
    # Difference Between This and Previous FULL == 1 Rows
    STEP_DIFF=df.loc[full_m, 'STEPS'] - df.loc[full_m, 'STEPS'].shift()
).groupby(
    # Create Groups Starting With Row After FULL == 1 ending with next FULL == 1
    df.FULL.shift().cumsum().fillna(0)
)[['STEP_DIFF', 'QUANTITY']].transform('sum')

# Place in the Averages or 0s
df['AVERAGE'] = np.where(full_m, sums.STEP_DIFF / sums.QUANTITY, 0)

# For Display
print(df.to_string())
```

Output:

```
                               CONTROL_ID   STEPS  QUANTITY  FULL   AVERAGE
ENGINE_ID TIME                                                             
A123B     2021-03-04 10:10:17           1  354815    156.32     1  0.000000
          2021-03-04 11:18:51           2  355160     85.49     0  0.000000
          2021-03-04 12:50:24           3  355428    100.00     0  0.000000
          2021-03-04 13:02:02           4  357850    157.02     1  8.861055
          2021-03-04 14:37:23           5  358314    134.00     0  0.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

First, get the cumulative sum for the quantities, then locate only the rows where the engine is full (FULL==1).

```
import numpy as np
df['cum']=df.QUANTITY.cumsum()
dffull=df[df.FULL==1]
```

Compute the consumption per STEP, using a numpy-array division of the deltas (therefore subtracting with shift of 1 index).

```
consumption=(np.array(dffull.iloc[1:].STEPS)-np.array(dffull.iloc[0:-1].STEPS))/(np.array(dffull.iloc[1:].cum)-np.array(dffull.iloc[0:-1].cum))
```

Now, assign the result. Because consumption list is one element shorter, first element set to 0 here.

```
dffull["consumption"]=[0]+list(consumption)
```

This is what dffull looks alike:

```
                               CONTROL_ID   STEPS  ...     cum  consumption
ENGINE_ID TIME                                     ...                     
A123B     2021-03-04 10:10:17           1  354815  ...  156.32     0.000000
          2021-03-04 13:02:02           4  357850  ...  498.83     8.861055
```

Finally, create a column consumption in the df, initialize by 0, then assign the values computed (you get a warning, it can be ignored), and done.

```
df["consumption"]=0
df["consumption"][df.FULL==1]=dffull.consumption
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution but I would use a sequence of `shift` operations like this:

```
import numpy as np

df['QUANT'] = df['QUANTITY'].shift(-1) # Shift QUANTITY by 1
df['GROUP'] = df['FULL'].cumsum() # Get a group number which increments when a 1 occurs in the FULL column

df2 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['GROUP'], keep='first') # Create a new dataframe dropping and keeping the first
df2['NEXT_STEPS'] = df2['STEPS'].shift(-1) # Shift the STEPS column by 1
df2['DIFF'] = df2['NEXT_STEPS'] - df2['STEPS'] # Get the difference between the previous and next steps which is 357850 - 354815
df = pd.merge(df.reset_index(), df2[['DIFF', 'GROUP']], on='GROUP') # Merge it with the original df


df = pd.merge(df, df.groupby('GROUP')['QUANT'].sum().reset_index(), on='GROUP') # Get the QUANTITY sum for each group and merge with original df
df['AVERAGE'] = (df['DIFF']/df['QUANT_y']).shift(1) # Calculate the AVERAGE
df['AVERAGE'] = np.where(df['FULL']==1, df.AVERAGE, 0) # Replace AVERAGE column with 0 where FULL is not 1 else keep it
df['AVERAGE'] = df['AVERAGE'].fillna(0) # Replace any nan with 0
df = df[['ENGINE_ID', 'TIME', 'CONTROL_ID', 'STEPS', 'QUANTITY', 'FULL', 'AVERAGE']]
```

To get a better understanding of what is happenind, I would suggest you break it down and print out the results.